# Xcode 9.4 + Only Test-flight app crash

Tags: release, testflight, xcode9.4, ios11.4

I reuploaded my app to TestFlight via Xcode 9.4 but it is continuously crash after splash screen on that test flight build in IOS 11 while same test flight working in IOS 10. While when running in the Adhoc build in the device, it is working fine without any issue.

And my last submission by Xcode 9.2 is working fine in all IOS devices including 11.4 too.

When I am getting crash logs from Organizer, it says, App crash on a statement like  `self.viewInput.refreshRewardCount(current: current, max: max)` where current and max value passed static as 0 and 50 respectively first time when app start.

Additionality, I have also checked my Optimization Flags for LLVM and Swift compiler which are set properly as my other app and people suggested on the stack too.

Help me to solve that issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this before.  If you have not resolved this try using ImageOptim (downloaded from the Mac AppStore) and optimize all of your images.  iOS 9 had a bug where it couldn't process certain metadata of PNG files.